# AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding'

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, web-scraping

My original code is this.

```
#py3.6, windows10   
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import codecs
import sys

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Reload is not supported. It was fixed.

```
Import importlib
Importlib.reload (sys)
```

But there was also an error.

> AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding'

How should I fix this? I would appreciate your help.

I also attach my entire code.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import codecs
import sys

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS('C:\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs')
url = u'https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&vertical=default&q=%EB%B0%B0%EA%B3%A0%ED%8C%8C%20since%3A2017-07-19%20until%3A2017-07-20&l=ko&src=typd&lang=ko'

browser.get(url)
time.sleep(1)

body = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")

start = time.time()
for _ in range(500):
    now = time.time()
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 
    document.body.scrollHeight);")
    print str(_) + "    seconds: " + str(now - start) 
    time.sleep(0.2)

tweets=browser.find_elements_by_class_name('tweet-text')

with codecs.open("test.txt", "w","utf-8") as f:
    i = 1
    for i, tweet in enumerate(tweets):
        data = tweet.text
        data = data.encode('utf-8')
        print i, ":", data
        msg = (str(data) +'\n')
        f.write(msg)
        i += 1

end = time.time()
print(end - start)
browser.quit()
```

Comment: Starting python 3.4, this function is no longer available.

Comment: Also `import` and `importlib`, not capitalized... please double-check what you're typing here ;)

Comment: btw, this latter code cannot possibly run on Python 3.6 as such!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should remove the `sys.setdefaultencoding`. Notice that this has been an abuse of `sys.setdefaultencoding` all along in Python 2 too. [From Python 2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setdefaultencoding):

> `sys.setdefaultencoding(name)`
>
> Set the current default string encoding used by the Unicode implementation. If name does not match any available encoding, LookupError is raised. **This function is only intended to be used by the `site` module implementation and, where needed, by `sitecustomize`. Once used by the `site` module, it is removed from the `sys` module’s namespace.**
>
> New in version 2.0.

This set the encoding for 8-bit strings in Python 2. Since bytestrings have *no* encoding in Python 3, and unicode strings (`str`) have neither (they're Unicode, but with opaque internal encoding), this function would be meaningless on Python 3 - there is *nothing* to set the default encoding for.

Comment: When I delete the phrase, I get a new error about the encoding ... It is so sad.

Comment: It does not mean that an error message appears.
However, all tweets are marked \ xeb \ xb0 \ xb0 \ xea \ xb3 \ xa0 \ xed \ in this way.
I can not solve this ...